# Excel COM Object Cast Error

Tags: c#, excel, garbage-collection

I'm trying to avoid "double dot" notation in my code (see [How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects)).  However, I get an error when I try to change the following code

```
Excel.Workbook oWB;
...
oWB.Sheets[oWB.Sheets.Count].Delete();
oWB.Sheets[oWB.Sheets.Count].Delete();
oWB.Sheets[oWB.Sheets.Count].Delete();
```

to this

```
Excel.Sheets oS;
oS = oWB.Sheets;
//error occurs in the following line
oS = oWB.Sheets[oS.Count];
oS.Delete();
oS.Delete();
os.Delete();
```

The error is `'Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D7-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).'`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare a new variable of type `Sheet`. `oS` is of type `Sheets`, while `oS.Sheets[os.Count]` is of type `Sheet` (without final 's'). As these are unrelated type from the runtime point of view, you must declare an intermediate variable with appropriate type `Sheet`.